# Does TCP support the option to keep the connection when IP changes?

Tags: android, mobile, tcp

I want to maintain a TCP connection even if IP changes in mobile environment.
Is there any option which support keeping connection when IP is changed on TCP?

I have checked the methods provided by the Java Socket class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A TCP connection is identified by a five-tuple, source IP, source port, protocol, dest IP, dest port.

So when the IP changes, the TCP connection changes.

> I want to maintain a TCP connection even if IP changes

Is an active TCP connection really what you need? You may have to use or implement another stateless/connectionless [transport layer protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer), for example [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol).

Comment: *"A TCP connection is identified by a five-tuple, source IP, source port, protocol, dest IP, dest port."* - the "TCP" of "TCP connection" is actually the "protocol" part. Thus a TCP connection is identified by a four-tuple only since it must already be true that the protocol is TCP.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. Now I'm considering protocol not only TCP connection. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure about my answer because I never tried, but TCP connection keeps tracks of IPs and ports to create connections, so I think that you can’t do it “natively”. Maybe you should write a method to tell the server that the ip associated with your MAC address is about to change. This is just a thought though, as I said before I never tried that.